# Objective-C AFNetworking iOS 10 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have working parsing codes for iOS 8, but when I want to open it with Xcode 8 gives me ;

> 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h

Error

How can I fix it? My codes below:

```
// 

        NSString *post3F = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomerId=%@&",idcus];

        NSData *postData3F = [post3F dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength3F = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData3F length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request3F = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request3F setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"update.php?"]];
        [request3F setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request3F setValue:postLength3F forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request3F setHTTPBody:postData3F];

        NSURLResponse *requestResponse3F;
        NSData *requestHandler3F = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request3F returningResponse:&requestResponse3F error:nil];

        NSString *requestReply3F = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler3F bytes] length:[requestHandler3F length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSArray *modelsAsArrayf3F = [requestReply3F componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *F = [modelsAsArrayf3F objectAtIndex:0];


//
```

Comment: First of all it's a warning not an error. Have you tried the suggestion? There are hundreds of related questions (and answers) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @vadian yeah but i have 130 more this warning in my project